# How to transfer List in Map>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-stream

I have workplaces and an amount with the currency that is stored in each of them. I need to convert this to Map, so that the key is the currency, and as the value - the amount from all jobs. For example, one workplace contains 20 US dollars and 40 Euros, and the second workplace contains 50 US dollars and 10 Euros. As a result, in the map should be - 70 US dollars and 50 Euros. How to doing this with `.stream()`?

Comment: Post your class and your input first dude.

Comment: can you post some code showing what you've already tried yourself

Comment: You forgot to post your code Artem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have some class `Workspace`, looking somewhat like this:

```
class Workspace {
    private List<Job> jobs;
    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }
}
class Job {
    private String currency;
    private int amount;
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Now you have a `List<Workspace>` that you want to turn into a `Map<String,Integer>`. This is easy:

```
workspaces.stream()
    .flatMap(w -> w.getJobs().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Job::getCurrency, Collectors.summingInt(Job::getAmount)));
```

If this is not what you want, you should edit and clarify your question.

Comment: In that case I would be glad if you can upvote and/or accept my answer.